# How can I make that Angular Material Buttons not scrolling over a sticky bar

Tags: css, angular, angular-material

I have an Angular app with a navigation bar on top that is sticky (position: sticky; top: 0;).
Under the navigation bar I have the content that contains Angular material components like mat-buttons or mat-cards. The problem is if I scroll the angular material components scroll over (appear on top of) the navigation bar.
How can I avoid that?
I have created a stackblitz that show the problem: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-fat76n?file=src/app/toolbar-overview-example.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to specify a `z-index` for your `.tool-bars` class.

```
.tool-bars {
  position: sticky;
  top: 0;
  z-index: 9999;
}
```

If you don't specify a z-index the browser will render elements which are defined later in your html on top.
By specifying a z-index you can control where the element should be drawn on the z-axis.

9999 is just an example, for a sticky navigation bar you typically choose a high value to guarantee that no other element will have a higher z-index.

Comment: I thought there should be an easy solution to that. I just could not find it.  Thank you so much. Very much appreciated.